# Peticion Ajax no funiona en subdominio

Tags: php, ajax

Estimados tengo el sitio **[www.ecuservicechile.cl](http://www.ecuservicechile.cl)** y su respetivo subdominio **portal.ecuservicechile.cl** el subdominio se encuentra en la carpeta portal. Adjunto imagen de la estructura de las carpetas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Problema 1** Como puedo hacer referencia a aquellos recursos y archivos que estan fuera de la carpeta portal, ya que al tratarse de un subdominio por mas **"../"** que ponga en las rutas relativas no consigo salir de dicha carpeta.

**Problema 2** Tengo una peticion ajax, donde el script php esta en la carpeta logica/creditos/listado_regiones.php, pero no se ejecuta la peticion y me da error

```
//MOSTRAR REGIONES//
function listado_regiones(){     
    var action = 'fetch_data';          
    $.ajax({        
        url:"<?php echo $raiz;?>logica/login/listado_regiones.php", 
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data:{ action:action},        
        success:function(data){
            $('.input_region').html(data.html1);        
            $('#region').change(function(){
                var $this = $(this), label = $this.prev("label");       
                if($this.val() === "") {
                    label.removeClass("active"); 
                }else{
                    label.addClass("active"); 
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Activaste `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` en el subdominio? Recuerda que solo con activar la cabecera para un dominio no basta

Comment: Eso es lo que desconozco, como debo hacer eso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que está pasando es un error de **CORS**, es decir que el servidor desconfía del origen de la petición

Para que el servidor pueda confiar en un origen, se debe incluir la cabecera `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, esta es la que determina qué orígenes están autorizados para hacer peticiones

Para ponerte contexto imagínate dos dominios: *dominio1* y *dominio2*, ahora supongamos que *dominio2* quiere hacer una petición a *dominio1*, esta petición será interceptada por el navegador el cual primero hará una petición `OPTIONS`, esta petición le dirá al navegador si *dominio1* admite peticiones de *dominio2*

De no admitirlo, se mostrará un breve mensaje

> Blocked by CORS Policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present...

**Ahora supongamos que *dominio1* admite peticiones de *dominio2***

Si la cabecera está bien configurada, la petición pasará inclusive a subdominios, sino esta será bloqueada en subdominios, pero NO será bloqueada en orígenes específicos

> **Importante:** La cabecera `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` es únicamente proporcionada
> por el servidor, no modificable desde el cliente

**¿Cómo habilitar `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`?**

Veo que tienes `.htaccess`, por lo que esta respuesta puede ser válida

Algo como esto debería servir en el `.htaccess` del dominio o subdominio de destino

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

**ATENCICÓN:** el string del final, es el origen que va a admitir, si es un asterisco, tu dominio va a admitir peticiones de **CUALQUIER** origen, si quieres admitir peticiones de un **dominio específico**, usa algo como esto

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://dominio.com"
```

En tu caso, deberías añadir la siguiente línea en el `.htaccess` de `www.ecuservicechile.cl` o `ecuservicechile.cl`

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "htpp://portal.ecuservicechile.cl"
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta se ah solucionado el problema